# Particle system on render showing ugly white volumes, How do I fix it? Happens for all Engines

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, particles, eevee-render-engine

I'm trying to spread flowers on the walking path on the right, but while rendering this converts into a weird white bubble. Why is this happening, it comes up in all engines.

[image]

Comment: hello, in the Particles panel, have you chosen the flower object?

Comment: @moonboots I think so yes. Here's a screen shot: https://imgur.com/a/YzGHDae
Also, my view is rendered view so if it shows up in this I don't get why not in final render

Comment: maybe share your file? Only keep the emitter and the particle object: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: @moonboots i removed all extra layers but still for some reason blender file size is like 1.4GB, not sure if that is expected. However, after removing extra layers, I see flowers rendering normally

Comment: if it's too heavy use another platform like workupload

Comment: The particle object's name is not fully visible, "Procedural..." There is a collection "Procedural Flower", is the object in there? Why is it called procedural, how did you create the object?